# Implement versioning of a RESTful API with PHP/Slim and Apache

Tags: php, api, rest, .htaccess, slim

I want to create a RESTful API with Apache/PHP and the Slim Framework (3.x). The API should support URI-based versioning like `<host>/rest/api/v1/<resource>` and `<host>/rest/api/latest/<resource>`.

Overall I found a solution which works, but I not really happy with my solution and I'm want to known what can I make better. I'm a rookie/newbie about Slim. I'm looking for new ideas and how I can improve my knowledge about Slim.

Every new version should be a new project, which a own independent code base. The version dispatching should be done by the Apache server and no in the PHP/Slim code. I found some example which implements different versions of the API in on project by using the group-method. But I'm not very happy with this solution. I feel better to have independent projects for independent versions.

- General improvements or comments?
- Do you have a better/simpler solution?
- Do you see problems in my solution?
- Improvements for .htaccess / rewrite rules
- Links to real implementations of a RESTful API with Slim
- ....

I'm looking forward for your answers and I'll be curious to see what's new.

---

The implementation of all version of the API are in the Apache `htdoc` folder with following structure

```
rest
 +--api
     +-v1
        +-.htaccess
        +-index.php
     +-v2
        +-.htaccess
        +-index.php
     +-.htaccess
     +-index.html
```

The implementation of the API are in the file `index.php`. Map calls like `/rest/api/v1/books` to my implementation I create in every version folder a `.htaccess` file which includes rules for the rewrite Apache module:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

In `index.php` I create some routes

```
$app->get('/books', function ...
$app->get('/books/{id}', function ...
```

Everything works fine if I use a explicit version in the URI (`<host>/rest/api/v2/books`). For convenience if I create an alias *latest* (`/rest/api/latest/books`), which redirect the alias-call to the latest version of the API version.

Therefore I create the file `rest/api/.htaccess` which rewrites the URI to an implementation:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^latest.*$ ./v2/index.php [QSA,L]
```

The rewrite rule works fine and the v2 implementation are called. But the routes don't match anymore. I found out that the original path is now part of the path.

```
/rest/api/v2/books -> /books
/rest/api/latest/books -> /rest/api/latest/books
```

If I modified the rules like this, it works - but I don't like to implement every rule twice.

```
$app->get('/rest/api/latest/books', function ...
$app->get('/rest/api/latest/books/{id}', function ...
```

Therefore I wrote a middleware function which trims `/rest/api/latest` from the path before the routes are matched.

```
$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $uri = $request->getUri();
    $path = $uri->getPath();
    if (substr($path,0,16) == "/rest/api/latest") {
        $uri = $uri->withPath(substr($path,16));
        return $next($request->withUri($uri), $response);
    }
    return $next($request, $response);
});
```

Now I can use the same rules for both cases, explicit version call and implicit version call.

Comment: ...not really worth posting as a proper review, but I recommend using `strpos($path, $needle) === 0` instead of `substr($path, 0, 16) == $needle`.  https://gist.github.com/vicb/1596588  (It is more of a habit rather than a micro-optimization for me because there is no need to extract the substring, just check if it is at position `0`.  Plus, if you ever need to adjust the needle, you don't have to recount the substring length with your finger on the monitor.)

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you for your answer. Yes you are absolutely right `strpos` is much better/nicer than `substr`. I cannot use my fingers, because I have only ten :-D